# Stop CollapsingToolbarLayout in AppBarLayout expanding when ScrollingView reaches top

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'd like to reach the same appbarlayout behaviour. As you can see from the gif below.

When the list reaches top, it doesn't trigger the appbarlayout to expand. It'll expand on a second scroll up.

Does anyone know a way to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to emulate that behaviour by doing these things:

consider this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the activity

```
list.setOnScrollChangeListener { list, _, _, _, _ ->
    list.isNestedScrollingEnabled = !list.canScrollVertically(-1)
}
```

This will do the trick.
I'm sure there are better ways to achieve that but this is how I solved it.